# Where can I find a description about the usage of "int C::*"?

Tags: c++, stl

In a piece of code, I find something as :

```
template<typename T>
class IsClassT {
  private:
    typedef char One;
    template<typename C> static One test(int C::*);
...
```

The question is where can I find a description about why the usage of "int C::*" is valid in function test() definition?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I won't describe what `int C::*` means since @Charles Bailey already did that very well. I will however answer your question:

> (...) why the usage of "int C::*" is valid in function test()
>   definition?

The key point is that the usage of `int C::*` (pointer to member of type `int`) is valid **if and only if** `C` is a class type. Otherwise the type `int C::*` is ill-formed.

This is why you have

```
template<typename C> static One test(int C::*);
```

and most probably somewhere below

```
template <typename> static Two test(...);
static const bool value = sizeof(test<T>(0)) == 1;
```

When `test<T>(0)` is seen by the compiler, it examines the candidates for `test`. It finds two:

```
template<typename C> static One test(int C::*);   
template <typename> static Two test(...);
```

The first has precedence over the second because 1) they are both template functions and 2) the ellipsis is looked up last. If the first one is ill formed (ie. *if and only if* `C` is not a class type), then it is simply **discarded** and the second overload is taken. This behaviour is nicknamed **SFINAE** (for Substitution Failure Is Not An Error).

Testing for the size of the return type (remember that `sizeof(char)` is always 1), you can assess at compile time which `test` is taken, ie. whether `T` is a class type or not.

Comment: I am reading "C++ Templates" and puzzled by this piece of code, your answer resolves my puzzle exactly  :o) Thanks

Comment: @Huang: this is a classical technique. You can read [the Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error) or google for SFINAE to know more about such compile time programs. Stackoverflow is also full of SFINAE tricks.

Answer (score 10):

`int C::*` is a pointer to a member of `C` of type `int`. Search for "pointer-to-member". The section of the standard (ISO/IEC 14882:2003) that deals with this declaration syntax is 8.3.3 Pointers to members [dcl.mptr].

Example usage.

```
struct Example
{
    int a;
    int b;
};

int test( Example& ex, int Example::* p )
{
    return ex.*p;
}

int main()
{
    Example x = { 3, 5 };
    // Convoluted way of extracting x.a and x.b
    int a = test( x, &Example::a );
    int b = test( x, &Example::b );
}
```

Comment: My bad if that's the case. How is it different from just int* then? Nvm, got it.

Comment: @Grozz: `int*` can be any reference to int(s) in general. however `int C::*` is a reference to an int that has to be a member of the `class C`

Comment: @Sujoy, I would say that "`int C::*` is a pointer to a member of `class C` which has type `int`". It's more precise.

Comment: @Sujoy: I pointer-to-member isn't - in and of itself - a restricted reference to an `int` because it isn't bound to a single `int` object. It's an entity that allows you to access a particular member from any instance of a particular class. It's more like an offset than a pointer.

Comment: @charles: yes. i was trying to imply that while `int *` can point to any `int', `int C::*` cannot. please correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 2):

It is a pointer to member.
A simple example to understand **Pointer to member**.

```
class A
{
   int a;
   int b;
   void DoSomething();
};

int main()
{
   A *ObjPtr;

   //pointer to member a
   int A::*ptr = &A::a;    

   //Usage
   objPtr->*ptr = NULL;

   //pointer to member function
   void (A::*FuncPtr)(void) = &A::DoSomething; 

   //Usage
   (objPtr->*FuncPtr)(void);    

   return 0;
}
```