# In IsClassT<T>, why use "int C::*"? I am confusing about the int type

Tags: c++, templates

An example described in book *C++ Templates The Complete Guide*:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class IsClass {
private:
    typedef char One;
    typedef struct { char a[2];} Two;

    template<typename C> static One test(int C::*);
    template<typename C> static Two test(...);

public:
    enum {
        Yes = (sizeof(IsClass<T>::test<T>(0)) == 1)
    };
    enum {
        No = !Yes
    };
};
```

I've read related topic [Where can I find a description about the usage of "int C::*"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6890331/where-can-i-find-a-description-about-the-usage-of-int-c)
I've got the concept that C::* means a pointer to member, and *test(0)* means *test(nullptr)*, but I have some other questions:

1. Suppose the compiler does not check if the class C really has a member of type *int*. Why compiler does not check?
2. The *int* type in *int C::** could be replaced by any type but *void*, although I think *void* is less confusing. Why this error reported?

```cpp
In file included from testisclass.cpp:12:
../inc/isclass.hpp:17:54: error: cannot declare pointer to ‘void’ member
   17 |         template<typename C> static One test(void C::*);
      |                                                      ^
../inc/isclass.hpp: In instantiation of ‘class IsClass<A>’:
testisclass.cpp:22:16:   required from here
../inc/isclass.hpp:17:41: error: creating pointer to member of type void
   17 |         template<typename C> static One test(void C::*);
      |                                         ^~~~
../inc/isclass.hpp: In instantiation of ‘class IsClass<int>’:
testisclass.cpp:28:18:   required from here
../inc/isclass.hpp:17:41: error: creating pointer to member of type void
```

3. *Yes* = true/false is a complete definition, why still *No* defined?

Comment: You can't have a `void` (member) variable, so what would `void C::*` refer to?

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my question before noticed your comment. But it does not matter. Just comment to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the Standard says so. In [[dcl.mptr]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.mptr):

> 3 - *Example*: [...] 
> `double X::* pmd;` 
> [...] The declaration of `pmd` is well-formed even though `X` has no members of type `double`. [...]
>
> 4 - A pointer to member shall not point to [...] “*`cv`*`void`”.

Some possible reasons: if you had to check data members, you wouldn't be able to define pointer to data members of incomplete classes. And while `void*` is useful for interoperability with C and for type erasure, C doesn't have pointer to member types, and it's unlikely that you'd ever need to type erase a pointer to member.

As for why `No` is defined in addition to `Yes` - no idea, perhaps the author thought it might be useful.

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my question before noticed your answer. But it does not matter. Just comment to clarify.